# C# Garbage data in string from unmanaged Method

Tags: c#, character-encoding, pinvoke, dllimport

I have a wrapper around an unmanaged Method:

```
[DllImport(DLL_LOCATION, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
private static extern Boolean voGetFirmwareVersion(StringBuilder s, ref uint d);
```

This is working fine, the StringBuilder is being filled with Chinese characters. Fortuantely I know what the text should read:

"Camera 0057; FPGA 0009"

What I am getting is:

慃敭慲〠㔰㬷䘠䝐⁁〰㤰猀״״譗珉譞珉쬂☐״״造琞\u085cʩ״

I have tried changing the CharSet to all combinations in my DLLImport flag and tried changing the returned strings encoding to no avail. Help me internet land!

EDIT: The dll I am calling belongs to a Device I am currently programming. All the other functions are working but the one mentioned above will only give me Chinese characters.

EDIT AGAIN: Below is the code I am using to call the method signature above:

```
private string getFirmware()
    {            
        uint r = 31;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(31);
        bool result = voGetFirmwareVersion(sb,  ref r);

        if(!result)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Getting Firmware");
        }     

        return sb.ToString();          
    }
```

Comment: which dll are you attempting to call?

Comment: question edited with the DLL information

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Code updated, I cant provide a verifiable example unless you happen to have an Access OCR640N device handy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the answer was to set the CharSet to None. By not having it there in the first place, it defaults to Unicode. I had assumed it would have been none.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up David, in previous posts I had been advised not to use Ansi. That totally works though.